# How to install the header files of a shared library with cmake?

Tags: cmake

Somehow I fail to parse the cmake documentation properly, and as a result the header files of a shared library are not installed. The library uses other system libraries, which are included via `pkg-config`. These CFLAGS and LDFLAGS are used properly during build.

What is required to install the contents of the `include` directory during `make install`?

With this pseudo-CMakeLists.txt the library gets installed, but no header gets installed:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Prj VERSION 1.2.3)
add_library(MyLib SHARED ${SOURCES})
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_module(EXTERNAL REQUIRED a b c)
target_include_directories(prj 
  PRIVATE
    ${EXTERNAL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../Some/Weird/Path
  INTERFACE
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/mylib>
  )
target_link_libraries(Prj ${EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES})
set_target_properties(Prj PROPERTIES VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION} SOVERSION 123)
include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS Prj
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
  INCLUDES DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
  )
```

Comment: I would also advice you to check out the post that @Tsyvarev recommended. Other than that, please provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).